# not loaded iframe that is contained in a HTML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, iframe

I have the following situation.  I have a jquery mobile page  with multiple pages.
The pages content in separate pages and are loaded with Jquery Ajax. 
In one of the page, there is a iframe  and its content comes from a jsp page.

HTML file one, is a jquery main pages with multiple page

```
<div id="page1" data-role="page" data-title="page1">

</div>  


<div id="page2" data-role="page" data-title="page2">

</div>  


<div id="page3" data-role="page" data-title="page3">

</div>
```

CONTENT of page 3 :

```
<div class="ui-header ui-bar-a ui-header-fixed" data-role="header" role="banner">
 </div>  

<div class="ui-content" data-role="content" role="main">
  ....
  <tr>
  <td valign="top">
      <iframe name="uploadIframe" src="uploadImage.jsp" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" scrolling="no" width="350" height="50" frameborder="1" ></iframe> 
  </td>
  </tr>

  ....
 </div>
```

The problem I have is that the iframe content which is  uploadImage.jsp   is not loaded.

Coould anyone help me ?

Comment: _"uploadImage.jsp is not loaded"_ -- do you get a 404 instead, or what?

Comment: @Frits van Campen I dont have the 404 error,   but when I try to access an element contained in the uploadImage.jsp file.
In one of my javascript file , i am doing : window.frames['uploadIframe'].document.getElementById('msgUpload')   and I got a null .
BUT when the whole page is loaded,  everything is there,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait for the content loaded event.

```
var doc = window.frames.uploadIframe.document;
doc.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () { /* ready */});
```